# mysql error IS NOT proper use?

Tags: mysql

Hello I am bit of a newb when it comes to mysql I running a query and I am getting the following error, to my knowledge the query syntax is correct (obvioulsy not though) this is the error that I am getting,

```
    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your  
 MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FAIL' AND `mc_subscriber.email` =  
 `mc_user.email`' at line 1
```

my mysql looks like this,

```
SELECT `mc_subscriber.email`, `mc_user.firstname`, `mc_user.lastname` FROM `subscriber`, `user` WHERE `mc_subscriber.status` = 'SUBSCRIBED` AND `mc_subscriber.status_mx` IS NOT = 'FAIL' AND `mc_subscriber.email` = `mc_user.email`;
```

I think I may be using IS NOT wrong, I trying to add a condtion that looks for all row where the mx_status is not equal to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tables called `subscriber` and `user`
Table labels of `mc_subscriber` and `mc_user`
Am I just being dense, or is there some sophisticated MySQL mechanism that autocorrelates the subscriber table with the mc_subscriber label?

And I thought if you used backticks in `` `mc_subscriber.email` ``, then both table and column should be individually backticked as `` `mc_subscriber`.`email` ``

Answer (score 1):

It should be: WHERE NOT column = value

so : NOT `mc_subscriber.status_mx` = 'FAIL'

edit: That works in PostgreSQL at least

edit2:

I wouldn't use that syntax in your case, instead I'd go with `mc_subscriber.status_mx` != 'FAIL' and use the "NOT column"-construct on boolean columns only. (It might be <> instead of != in MySQLs case don't know for sure)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `mc_subscriber.email`, `mc_user.firstname`, `mc_user.lastname` FROM `subscriber` WHERE `mc_subscriber.status` = `SUBSCRIBED` AND `mc_subscriber.status_mx` IS NOT = `FAIL` AND `mc_subscriber.email` = `mc_user.email`;
```

Give that ago.

Looks like you was wrapping with he incorrect quotes, you only really need to use qoutes where "sending" as string such as

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE somecolumn = '<Some String>' and someint = 1;
```

the Qoutes `''` are not really needed in columns

Also if your having issues with the `IS NOT = 'FAIL'` section try changing it to `UPPER(mc_subscriber.status_mx) != 'FAIL'`

Peace and much love :)